# Open a new winform by doubleclick and close the caller window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winform called `Form1`, and this winform has a list and a button.
I added a `click()` event to the button, and a `doubleclick()` event to the list. 
Both events call to the same method: (in *form1.designer.cs*)

```
this.myList.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.myMethod);
this.myButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMethod);
```

In `myMethod`, I want to do the following operations:

1. open a new winform of kind `Form2`, and make it the active winform.
2. close the caller winform (of kind `Form1`), there is no need for this form anymore.

I did it like this: (in *form1.cs*)

```
private void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form2 frm = new Form2();                 
     this.dispose();
}
```

when `myMethod` is being called by list doubleclick event, when `myMethod` ends, there is a null pointer exception.
When it's being called by the button click event, it works properly.

I tried `this.close()` as well, and got the same behavior.

my questions:

1. How should I write `myMethod` properly so it will make the wanted operations for the button click event and also for the list doubleclick event?
2. What is the difference between the button and the list? why does it work properly for the button, but crashes for the list?

Thanks

Comment: Is the calling form actually closing?

Comment: You should call the Form.Close method, not Dispose.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx

Comment: i tried with this.Close as well, same problem.

Comment: neoistheone, form1 is actually closing. As I see it, that may be the reason for the exception. But I don't understand how it works well for the button click.

Comment: Post the contents of your `Main` method (typically in Program.cs).

Comment: Is this the real code? Is there a reference to an instance of Form1 somewhere else?

Comment: Calling Form.Close in the event handler for a ListBox DoubleClick event will not raise any exceptions.  Are you sure you removed the Dispose method?  Are you sure you're not referencing Form1 elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you all :)

Comment: @user1439691 What is List?. ListView or ListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `Form1` and show `Form2`. This will raise some issue like closing `Form2`
won't close `Form1`.

```
this.Hide();
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```